# How do I get the values of all System.String from .dmp-file with Windbg

Tags: c#, windbg

I'm trying to analyse a w3wp process dump file with Windbg, I'm interested in finding out all the string values in memory. But I can't find a way. So is there a way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you can do this with the `sosex` extension for windbg:

The command `!sosex.strings` will dump out the strings in the heap.

[This is a fairly good blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scottos/archive/2010/05/12/how-to-extract-count-and-sort-strings-pulled-from-a-managed-dump-file.aspx) explaining how to install sosex and use the command.